# Table size calculation and optimization

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2012

I have a table with below column data types:

```
(BIGINT,NOTNULL)   X 5 
(TINYINT,NOTNULL)  X 2 
(DATETIME,NOTNULL) X 1
```

The table has about 300M records and use near 180GB disk space.

```
EXEC sp_spaceused N'my_table';
```

returns this result:

```
rows        reserved        data            index_size      unused
278475702   123318224 KB    24262784 KB     98972504 KB     82936 KB
```

but I think something is wrong about config or design. How can I find that this disk usage is right or not?

Is there any way to optimize disk usage for this table?

Comment: Is there a unique index / primary key? which type?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, both of them exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice reports available to analyze disk usage easier, but that won't make it less: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/

If the database was once larger and you have removed a lot of data, you could use the [`DBCC SHRINKFILE`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/08/01/sql-server-ssms-disk-usage-report/) function to reduce the size. Seeing as you have 123GB reserved, I think this could help you a lot.

Additionally, completely rebuilding the indexes can help a lot too.

- Drop all non-clustered indexes and create them again after
- Reindex the clustered index (if you have one)
- If you don't have a clustered index, create it (and optionally drop it after). This reorganizes your table and releases space that's used in-between the rows.